# Warning: failed prop 'style' of type 'number' expected `object` in styles (Container) in react native

Tags: react-native, styles, warnings

I'm having this awkward but annoying warning in every single page of my app and i did searched for the word "number " and i'm sure i didn't use it in any of the pages. any idea or suggestion to fix this ? [image]

Comment: Look like you trying to pass React Native Stylesheet to style property of Styled(?) component but it should be object.

Comment: thank you .. but i didn't understand you very well .. can you please explain more or give me an example PS: i'm using native base and i'm restyling it's components ..

Comment: React Native packager transforms all Stylesheets to native styles and passes it as references (numbers) to components. I don't know what Styled component is but look like it is expecting style should be object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem ,NativeBase doing it to me too ,its not solution but suggestion to get rid of this, do not create styleSheet just give your css like style={{color:""}}

Comment: ok i'll try it out now and if it's working i'll mark it as an answer.. thanks really